# How to make Teredo hosts within a subnet talk to each other

Tags: networking, ipv6, tunneling

While I can successfully ping a global address from my teredo-enabled end-host, I'm unable to connect two end-host within the same ipv4 subnet. We are running windows XP. Any thoughts?

Comment: I misread this at first and was confused, since teredo doesn't provide users with an ipv6 subnet.  But now I see that you're asking about an ipv4 subnet - makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: use the link local address. This can be formed by using the mac address and other available info.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug with winxp sp3 teredo implementation. Winxp SP3 doesn't send multi-cast bubble packets when behind the same router. As of now there is no solution. But at times it sends multi-cast packets & reaches the system in the same sub-net.